# Swift 3 Fetch Request Error (warning: could not load any Objective-C class information)

Tags: core-data, nsfetchrequest, swift3

I recently received this error when fetching data from Core Data:

warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.
(lldb)

Here is my code:

```
// MARK: - Initialize Fetch Request

var fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<Profile>()

func setFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Profile> {

    let request = Profile.fetchRequest()
    let sortDescriptor = SortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: false)

        do {
            try moc?.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            print("Error With Request: \(error)")
        }
        request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    return setFetchRequest()
}


// MARK: - Retrieve Fetch Request

func getFetchRequest() -> NSFetchedResultsController<Profile> {

    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: setFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: moc!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    return fetchedResultsController
}
```

I crashed with this error where I have "try moc?.fetch(request)":

Thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16fc07feo)

Are these errors connected or is this a bug in Swift 3 / Xcode 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't take results from the `ManagedObjectContext`. If you want to use a `NSFetchedResultsController` class in your app? You'll need to access their methods. And all of the required or optional methods are comes from the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol.

Try this

`class YourTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
var fetchedResultsController:NSFetchedResultsController<Profile>!
}`

And then create a custom helper function like this one:

`func frc() {

```
    let request:NSFetchRequest<Profile> = Profile.fetchRequest()
    let sorter = SortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [sorter]

    self.fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    // make sure the delegate is set to self
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    do {
     try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {} 
}
```

`

From this point you'll need a trigger to perform operations. So let's the system itself should be doing this when you call the `viewDidLoad` method or you can create a button instead. For example click the button to begin operations.

`override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.frc()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }`

It should be works.
Good luck!

**Automatic Subclass Generation**

*Xcode 8* and *Swift 3* comes with a new generation of subclassing called as *Automatic Subclass Generation*! How to create it? Well! So let's create a new *Xcode* 8 project, choose a *Single View Application* and then another window will appears called *Choose options for your new project:*. Give the name for your new project, make sure language is a Swift and *Use Core Data* check box is checked and then hit *Create*.

Go to the `YourProjectName.xcdatamodeld` file and click it. And then add an entity! So let's say your entity name is a *Profile* and create their *Attributes* respectively. It's important to know, because this is an *Automatic Subclass Generation*. Choose your entity and go to the *Data Model Inspector* ! Choose a *Class Definition* for the `Codegen` [You can find a *Codegen* from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T71Pe.png).

After selected the *Class Definition*, you can see *Name* text field automatically filled by your entity name [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTUcF.png). Again go to the your entity and click it. Click *Command + S* for save changes firstly and then click *Command + B* for rebuild, that's it. **Automatic Subclass Generation** is successfully created.

**Remember**

If you want to change your model? For example: If you want to add a new *Attribute* to your model? It's very easy, select a `xcdatamodeld` file and click your `entity`. Click the plus sign under `Attributes` and add your new *Attribute*. After your changes is completed? Don't forget to save changes. Again click *Command + S* and then click *Command + B*

**Create A Managed Object**

In the *Swift 3* you can create a `ManagedObject` by using subclass initializer. It's very easy to implementing than ever before

`let managedObject = Profile(context: self.managedObjectContext!)`

You can see it's very easy! How to save values to the `managedObject` ? So let's say you have a `title` attribute of your model. Also `title` is a `String`.

`managedObject.setValue("Well crafted API? Right?", forKey: "title")`

or

`managedObject.title = "Well crafted API? Right?"`

Save values:

`do {
 try self.managedObjectContext.save()
   print(managedObject)
} catch {}`

It's works well on the **Swift 3.0** beta and **Xcode 8.0** beta.

Comment: **Cannot convert value type 'NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>' to expected argument to type 'NSFetchRequest<_>'** I even tried request<Profile> but that returned this error **Cannot specialize a non-generic definition** I am still not clear what NSFetchRequestResults is even after reading the definition.

Comment: Swift 3 comes with Automatic Subclass Generation. Make sure you're correctly create a subclass of the NSManagedObject.

Comment: Perhaps you're not checked a Codegen field from your Data Model Inpector or you're not saved your staff yet.

Comment: Right. I migrated to Swift 3 (beta) and Xcode 8 (beta) current syntax. I assume my xcdatamodel was considered. It is the same as it was before. Should I regenerate an NSManaged Subclass?

Comment: What do you mean by **Codegen field from your Data Model Inpector or you're not saved your staff yet**

Comment: It's about a new feature of the Core Data in Swift 3

Comment: You shouldn't regenerate a subclass! Because Xcode itself doing this when you're migrated. I don't know it's correct or not. But try this: Click the xcdatamodel and select your Entity ( Profile ), and then go to the Data Model Inspector. You can find a Codegen check boxes under Class and choose a " Class Definition ".  Command + S ( save changes ) and finally Command + B ( Rebuild ). I've not tried yet but it's should works.

Comment: I feel like the **self.fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: self.moc!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)** should work but the request is wrong. In Swift 2, I used a function. I tried **NSFetchRequest<Profile>()** but I got an error that said **instance of fetch request requires sort descriptors** which I have above after initializing SortDescriptors, which is simply request.sortDescriptors = [sorter]. This is really driving me crazy.

Comment: Do not need " () ". Please delete them. Xcode asks " how fetch request should be? " and just say to Xcode " let request: NSFetchRequest<YourSubclass>  = YourSubclass.fetchRequest() ". And you can put sort descriptors to the request object using dot syntax. " request.sortDescriptors = [ sortDescriptor ]. It's depending your choice

Comment: Your apps works on the Xcode 7.x.x ? This app works before?

Comment: The original code I posted works with Xcode 7.x.x. Code does not compile with Xcode 8 and Swift 3 because NSFetchResultsController and NSFetchRequest are Generics. This **let request: NSFetchRequest<YourSubclass> = YourSubclass.fetchRequest()** only works after I did this **@nonobjc class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Giver> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Giver>(entityName: "Giver");
    }** to my CoreDataProperties file.

Comment: I have tried every permutation and have gotten no where. I am now essentially copying Apple's Master-Detail example and trying to update my fetch the way they do it. Still having problems but making progress. I'll let you know if I crack it. Also, if you could reproduce a fetch request in Swift 3 using Xcode 8, that be great. Cannot find one. Apple's works, not surprisingly.

Comment: If you want to create a new app using Core Data & Swift 3 & iOS 10 & NSFetchedResultsController? I'll help you

Comment: Cool. Give me a day. I may have something. Thanks a lot. Will get back to you tomorrow!

Comment: I should mention I am fetching images e.g. image: Binary Data in Core Data. I am no longer crashing but nothing is showing up. I am getting errors like this **FigPhotoJPEGDecodeSession >>>> **** Warning: Converting CGImage's IOSurface backing from 420f to BGRA/L555 on demand. This is slow. If you intend to draw using CG or otherwise access the bytes directly use a BGRA surface instead.** Just a heads up. We'll get it!

Comment: I've updated my answer! It's about how to create a Automatic Subclass Generation. Tomorrow I will provide how to save values to the ManagedObject. See you

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

So, this is what I got working for Xcode 8 beta and Swift 3 beta Core Data

```
var fetchedResultsControler = NSFetchedResultsController<Profile>()

func frc() {

let request: NSFetchRequest<Profile> = Profile.fetchRequest()

let sortDescriptor = SortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

self.fetchedResultsControler = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: self.moc!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

self.fetchedResultsControler.delegate = self

do {
try self.fetchedResultsControler.performFetch()
} catch {
    print("Error Fetching Data: \(error)")
    }
}
```

and in viewDidLoad I have     self.frc() at the top of the viewDidLoad.

So, in my Profile+CoreDataProperties.swift I copied a method Apple uses in their Master-Detail example when you create a new project:

extension Profile {

```
@nonobjc class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Profile> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Profile>(entityName: "Profile");
}
@NSManaged var title: String?
@NSManaged var titleImage: Data
```

}

so that my fetch request is "native to my function." Pretty sure that's not the correct way to say that but it's helping me understand what is going on. The fetch request in Apple's example is green instead of blue. And it took me forever to notice that. I clicked on "Event" in Apple's example, and was conveniently taken to the created subclass, which was demonstrated in the Xcode 8 video at WWDC.

The files for e.g. Event.swift and Event+CoreDataProperties.swift are not exposed like they are in Xcode 7.x.x and earlier. You have to click on the entity in the code and you'll be taken to them. Maybe that was my problem? Anyway, I'm fetching data and images like a champ. Thanks a lot for your help @Mannopson!